# ionic invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries

Tags: ionic3, pdfmake

The error is ionic invalid image, images dictionary should contain dataURL entries, How do I fix this error.

var docDefinition = {

```
  content: [

    { text: 'Dr. ' + this.letterObj.From, style: 'header' },
    { text: new Date().toLocaleString(), alignment: 'center' },
    { text: this.dloc, alignment:'center'},
    // { text: 'TEL: (631) 22431243  FAX:(631) 1325423', alignment: 'center'},
    { text: '__________________________________________________________', alignment: 'center'},
    { text: 'Name:', style: 'subheader' },
    this.full,
    {text: 'Rx', style: 'rx'},

    // { text: 'From', style: 'subheader' },
    // { text: this.letterObj.From },

    { image: '..assets/imgs/rx.png', width:100},

    { text:this.letterObj.text, style: 'story', margin:[0,20,0,20] },

    {

    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image path `image: '..assets/imgs/rx.png'` is invalid.

When an image property is a path to a file, you can get this error if the path is not valid.

First, try with this path: `image: '../assets/imgs/rx.png'`

Then if it's still not working, verify that the parser resolves the relative path correctly.